# Delete previous entry and update table with current entry - mySql

Tags: mysql

Say below is my table

```
entryID  ID    Number    locationId  timestamp  
331      136   7         1           5/30/2018 9:23     
332      136   7         1           5/30/2018 9:25  
333      136   9         1           5/30/2018 9:25         
334      136   11        1           5/30/2018 9:25    
335      136   11        1           5/30/2018 9:25    
336      136   9         1           5/30/2018 9:26    
337      137   1         2           6/4/2018 8:45    
338      137   2         2           6/4/2018 8:47  
339      137   7         2           6/4/2018 8:47  
340      137   7         2           6/4/2018 8:47
```

I would want to filter them by ID and locationId, delete the duplicate rows ("Number" is the column which carries duplicate values) and see the results as shown below after querying the table filtered by locationId = 1.

```
entryID  ID    Number    locationId  timestamp    
332      136   7         1           5/30/2018 9:25   
335      136   11        1           5/30/2018 9:25    
336      136   9         1           5/30/2018 9:26    
337      137   1         2           6/4/2018 8:45    
338      137   2         2           6/4/2018 8:47  
339      137   7         2           6/4/2018 8:47  
340      137   7         2           6/4/2018 8:47
```

If locationId = 2, below is the result I would expect to see.

```
  entryID    ID    Number    locationId  timestamp  
  331        136   7         1           5/30/2018 9:23     
  332        136   7         1           5/30/2018 9:25  
  333        136   9         1           5/30/2018 9:25         
  334        136   11        1           5/30/2018 9:25    
  335        136   11        1           5/30/2018 9:25    
  336        136   9         1           5/30/2018 9:26    
  337        137   1         2           6/4/2018 8:45    
  338        137   2         2           6/4/2018 8:47
  340        137   7         2           6/4/2018 8:47
```

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this for all locations in one go?

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is poorly explained. Nevertheless, assuming that timestamp really is a timestamp, then I suspect that you're after something like this...

(Remember to back up your data prior to deleting anything!!!)

```
DELETE x
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT locationid
            , number
            , MAX(entryid) entryid 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY locationid
            , number
     ) y 
    ON y.locationid = x.locationid 
   AND y.number = x.number 
   AND y.entryid = x.entryid
 WHERE y.entryid IS NULL;
```